# Compare two images in Monkeyrunner under windows

Tags: python, imagemagick, python-imaging-library, monkeyrunner

I am trying to compare two images that are taken from monkeyrunner.
I found that there is `sameAs` in monkeyrunner but it seems to not work.
There are two other ways, one is install package ImageMagick, but I don't know how to install and use it under windows, the useful information just could be used in Linux system.
Another way is using ImageChop of PIL library of Python.
I just want to check the images are the same or not.
Is there another way to check how many percentage that the images are different?

Comment: I found a solution from Raja http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/174663

Answer (score 0):

I would use PhotoShop. Put 2 images in 2 layers, make "Difference" blending, and you may see difference in pixels visually, or when you choose Histogram from menu. Histogram values shown as zeros mean identical images.

PShop layers:
[image]

Histogram:
[image]

Visual difference (may be harder to spot)
[image]

This test is from image loaded in RGB 888 pixel format vs RGB 565 pixel format, so there's slight difference in result.